# Send latitude and longitude data to textview

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I wrote the code below, where the search for latitude and longitude is performed based on the address entered by the enduser.

The class `CadastroClientes.java`. It is responsible for seeking the user's address (`HttpRequestTask` method) and set this result to `char_Logradouro` field (textvfield).

After set the value in the mentioned field, `BuscaGeolocalizacao` class is called and the `getAddressFromLocation` method passing as parameter, the address you entered. So far everything was running right.

The problem started when in the `BuscaGeolocalizacao` class I tried to set the value of the result of `latitude` and `longitude` on the fields:

```
cc.char_Lat.setText(sb.append(address.getLatitude()));
cc.char_Long.setText(sb.append(address.getLongitude()));
```

**CadastroClientes.java** (first code called)

```
package com.clubee.doggywalker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CadastroClientes extends Activity {

    //JSON node
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    //url para cadastrar novo usuário
    private static String url_cadastraCliente = "http://clubee.com.br/dev/dbDoggyWalker/DoggyWalker_CadastroCliente_Inserir.php";
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText char_Nome;
    EditText char_CEP;
    EditText char_Email;
    EditText char_Cidade;
    EditText char_Estado;
    EditText char_Logradouro;
    EditText char_Endereco;
    EditText char_Bairro;
    TextView char_Lat;
    TextView char_Long;



    //barra de progressão
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cadastro_dw);

        char_Nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNome);
        char_Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        char_Logradouro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLogradouro);
        char_Cidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCidade);
        char_Estado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEstado);
        char_Bairro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputBairro);
        char_CEP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCEP);
        char_Lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLatitude);
        char_Long = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLongitude);

        //Criar botão
        Button btnCadastraCliente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCadastraCliente);
        Button btnBuscaCEP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscaEndereco);

        //Criar evento do botão
        btnCadastraCliente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //abre thread em background
                new CadastraCliente().execute();
            }
        });

        //Criar evento do botão
        btnBuscaCEP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //abre thread em background
                new HttpRequestTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, DAOPostmon > {
        String charCepTrim = char_CEP.getText().toString().trim();
        final String url = "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/" + charCepTrim;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        @Override
        protected DAOPostmon doInBackground(Void...params) {
            try {
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                DAOPostmon DAOPostmon = restTemplate.getForObject(url, DAOPostmon.class);
                return DAOPostmon;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                DAOPostmon DAOPostmon = restTemplate.getForObject(url, DAOPostmon.class);
                return DAOPostmon;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(DAOPostmon DAOPostmon) {

            //quando a tag Logradouro estiver disponiivel no retorno da api rest
            if (DAOPostmon.getLogradouro() == null) {

                TextView greetingLogradouro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLogradouro);
                TextView greetingBairro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputBairro);
                TextView greetingCidade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCidade);
                TextView greetingEstado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputEstado);
                TextView greetingCEP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCEP);
                greetingLogradouro.setText(DAOPostmon.getEndereco().toUpperCase());
                greetingCidade.setText(DAOPostmon.getCidade().toUpperCase());
                greetingBairro.setText(DAOPostmon.getBairro().toUpperCase());
                greetingEstado.setText(DAOPostmon.getEstado().toUpperCase());
                greetingCEP.setText(DAOPostmon.getCep());
            } else {

                //senão, quando não tiver a tag logradouro, usar endereco

                TextView greetingLogradouro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputLogradouro);
                TextView greetingBairro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputBairro);
                TextView greetingCidade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCidade);
                TextView greetingEstado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputEstado);
                TextView greetingCEP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputCEP);
                greetingLogradouro.setText(DAOPostmon.getLogradouro().toUpperCase());
                greetingCidade.setText(DAOPostmon.getCidade().toUpperCase());
                greetingBairro.setText(DAOPostmon.getBairro().toUpperCase());
                greetingEstado.setText(DAOPostmon.getEstado().toUpperCase());
                greetingCEP.setText(DAOPostmon.getCep());
            }


            String address = char_Logradouro.getText().toString();
            BuscaGeolocalizacao locationAddress = new BuscaGeolocalizacao();
            locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(address,
            getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());
        }
    }

    private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
        public void handlerMsg(Message message) {
            String locationAddress;
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:
                    Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                    locationAddress = bundle.getString("char_Logradouro");
                    char_Lat.setText(locationAddress);
                    break;
                default:
                    locationAddress = null;
            }
        }
    }

    class CadastraCliente extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CadastroClientes.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Cadastrando usuário..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
            String Nome = char_Nome.getText().toString();
            String Email = char_Email.getText().toString();
            String Endereco = char_Endereco.getText().toString();
            String TipoLicenca = "DogWalker";


            // Building Parameters
            List < NameValuePair > params = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("char_Nome", Nome));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("char_Email", Email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("char_Endereco", Endereco));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("char_TipoLicenca", TipoLicenca));


            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_cadastraCliente,
                "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CadastroClientes.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**BuscaGeolocalizacao.java** (the class responsible to return lat/long)

```
package com.clubee.doggywalker;

import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class BuscaGeolocalizacao {

private static final String TAG = "GeocodingLocation";

public static void getAddressFromLocation(final String locationAddress,
                                          final Context context, final Handler handler) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            String result = null;
            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                    CadastroClientes cc = new CadastroClientes();
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");
                    result = sb.toString();
                    cc.char_Lat.setText(sb.append(address.getLatitude()));
                    cc.char_Long.setText(sb.append(address.getLongitude()));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to connect to Geocoder", e);
            } finally {
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.setTarget(handler);
                if (result != null) {
                    message.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
                            "\n\nLatitude and Longitude :\n" + result;
                    bundle.putString("address", result);
                    message.setData(bundle);
                } else {
                    message.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
                            "\n Unable to get Latitude and Longitude for this address location.";
                    bundle.putString("address", result);
                    message.setData(bundle);
                }
                message.sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
}
```

After the attempt to implement sending `latitude` and `longitude` for activity, the system started to explode with the following message

> 07-01 00:44:18.412    8978-9170/com.clubee.doggywalker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-23081
>       Process: com.clubee.doggywalker, PID: 8978
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>               at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200)
>               at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114)
>               at android.app.Activity.(Activity.java:793)
>               at com.clubee.doggywalker.CadastroClientes.(CadastroClientes.java:27)
>               at com.clubee.doggywalker.BuscaGeolocalizacao$1.run(BuscaGeolocalizacao.java:33)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post on the UI thread also like

```
cc.char_Lat.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            cc.char_Lat.setText("what ever value");
        }
    });
```

But by the way i think you should use your handler instead of using a reference to CadastroClientes

Comment: Hello Jarp, I understand your mention, but my doubt is how. How I could send the param using the handler method? btw, you referred to the GeocoderHandler, am I right?

Comment: Hi Barcat , yes you are right i´m referring yo GeocoderHandler, for example you could instantiate your handler on the onCreate
Handler h = new Handler(CadastroClientes.this.getMainLooper()); //this way it has a reference to the UI 
So then you can post a Runnable or a Message what ever you like.
Here is a very little example maybe it can help you [Handlers](https://github.com/imjarp/101AndroidExamples/blob/master/04-BasicHandler/app/src/main/java/jarp/mx/com/basichandler/MainActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

do your UI operations in a **UI Thread**. Like this..

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                cc.char_Lat.setText(sb.append(address.getLatitude()));
                cc.char_Long.setText(sb.append(address.getLongitude()));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Android basically works on two thread types namely UI thread and background thread. According to android documentation -

*Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread to fix this problem, Android offers several ways to access the UI thread from other threads. Here is a list of methods that can help:*

```
 Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)  
 View.post(Runnable)  
 View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
```

> 

```
new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            myactivity.this.runOnUiThread(new runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                  cc.char_Lat.setText(sb.append(address.getLatitude()));
                  cc.char_Long.setText(sb.append(address.getLongitude()));

                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if(location != null) {
    showAddress(location);
}

final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        showAddress(loc);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);


private void showAddress(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    Geocoder myLoc = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());   
    List<Address> mlist;
    try {
        mlist = myLoc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if(mList.size() == 1) {                 char_Lat.SetText(mlist.get(0).getLatitude().toString());                char_Long.Settext(mlist.get(0).getLongitude().toString());           
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        log.e("IO Exception",e.Message);
    }
}
```

use Location Permission in your Manifest :

android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html